# Where is the Rails app log on ubuntu server (nginx+passenger+capistrano)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

We have a Rails 6 app, which is being deployed to an Ubuntu server with the following setup:

Nginx 1.17 & passenger 6, releases are deployed using capistrano v3

I could find the following log files:

- Nginx (access & error logs):

`/var/log/nginx/access.log` & `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

- Passenger logs: (on staging env)

`/home/deploy/myapp/current/log/staging.log`

The logs written in Passenger logs (which is the one that shall have the application log as I understand), has only Ruby logs for the Table migrations and creation but not ruby application log

So none of the above logs have the Rails application logs (i.e.: the log that shows Rails details like the `rails s` output in the dev env) & the nginx access log shows only the static assets logs when a page is loaded but not the ruby or the sql logs

The logical place to me, `staging.log file`, only has stale log data & doesn't get any new Rails logs written to it

Where is the Rails application logs please?

Comment: Are you sure the application is run in the `staging` environment? (check your passenger configuration). Other options: Is there a custom logger defined in the `config/environment/staging.rb` or `config/aplication.rb` (e.g. logging to syslog or an external logging service like loggly or datadog?)

Comment: Thanks a million Natahan, your fantastic advice showed me the issue, thanks a lot, I will put it as an answer but credit goes to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Guided by Nathan comment & credit for solving this goes to him:

### The cause of the issue is:

In the `staging.rb`, I had this config for the logs

& the env variable was defined as `export RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT='enabled'`

```
  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end
```

**So removing the env variable:**

`RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT='enabled'`

Allowed the Rails log to show as expected in the correct directory:

`/home/user/project-name/current/log/staging.log`

Answer (score 2):

Rails writes its logs by default to the `log/ENVIRONMENT.log` file (where `ENVIRONMENT` is replaced by the value of your `RAILS_ENV` environment variable.

On your production environment, the logs are thus likely written to `/home/deploy/myapp/current/log/production.log`

Note that Rails tries to create that file if it doesn't exist. If the user running your app doesn't have the necessary permissions to create (or write to) the file, it doesn't write logs at all.

Comment: Thanks for the help @holger, it turns out to be something in the staging configuration that I didn't note as Nathan pointed out